# .htaccess + wordpress, multiple directory redirects

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am moving about 38 websites from Joomla over to wordpress.

I want to keep the same linking structure becuase of SEO. unfortunately the last developer was careless with the way they structured their links, so I have some wacky requirements to fulfill.

i.e sometimes their blog is index.php/blog-4, and at the same time index.php/blog, and index.php/blog-5.

In wordpress, I made the permalinks be

index.php/blog-5/%postname%

I've never edited .htaccess before, but what I would like to do is to redirect anything that goes to

/blog/* --> /blog-5/*

/blog-4/* --> /blog-5/*

What would I write to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

I'm having trouble implementing Michael's answer. Here's how my .htaccess looks like. Ive tried putting it both inside and outside of .

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog-5
RewriteRule ^blog(-.+)?/(.*) blog-5/$2 [L,R=301]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly simple `RewriteRule`.  Use the expression `(-4)?` to optionally match the `-4` and redirect it to `/blog-5` along with requests to `/blog/`.  The second `(.*)` group after the `/` captures everything else into `$2`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog(-4)?/(.*) blog-5/$2 [L]
```

The above will do a silent internal rewrite. If you actually want to redirect and have the browser show the new URL, change `[L]` to `[L,R=301]`.

Note: Realizing `blog-4` is probably a variable name, use `(-.+)?` to match anything. But you also need a `RewriteCond` so it *doesn't match* `blog-5`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog-5
RewriteRule ^blog(-.+)?/(.*) blog-5/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the fast answer. This makes sense. I tried adding this in, though I'm not seeing the redirect happen. It might be because of the way I wrote it in my .htaccess file. I've updated the question with the htaccess file. Thoughts greatly appreciated

Comment: @StepanParunashvili Sorry I missed your comment, not sure why I didn't see the notification.  It looks like the `RewriteRule . /index.php` is probably being matched first.  Comment out that line to test the new rules. Probably then you need to add it back as the _last_ rule.

Comment: @StepanParunashvili I see you marked it accepted again, so I hope that worked out for you.

Comment: I've yet to try it, but your explanation makes a lot of sense :). Thanks Michael.